# solr search keywords with nid 333

Tags: solr

I have a simple schema:

```
 <fields>
    <field name="mongo_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="nid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />
 </fields>
```

I want to return results that match keywords AND have a certain nid.

```
$query = $_GET['q'];
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', 8983, '/solr/');
$results = $solr->search($query, 0, $limit);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use a filter query:

```
$additionalParameters = array('fq' => 'nid:333');
$results = $solr->search($query, 0, $limit, $additionalParameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query would look something like this:

```
?q=+keywords:keyword +nid:nid
```

Of course the + signs should be URL encoded if you're calling the Solr web service: %2B is the encoding for a +. The reason for this is that otherwise the + will be interpreted as a space.

Also, if the `keywords` field is being searched by default, you can omit `keywords:` in the query above.

Comment: I won't want the user to have to put nid:333...is it bad to hardcode?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't hard-code. On the other hand you could have a SELECT on the previous page of node IDs from which the user could choose. The "fq" option from @samuelg 's post above for `nid` might be even better as `fq` signifies a filter query which will not affect the score of the result.